# A question about solutions of O.D.E $(2x^2+2y^2+x)dx+(x^2+y^2+y)dy=0,\ x\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I solved firstly the O.D.E $$(*)\ \ \ \ (2x^2+2y^2+x)dx+(x^2+y^2+y)dy=0, x\geq 0, $$ by using the Integrating Factor $\rho (x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$. Consequently, I proved that every solution $y$ of this equation is given by form:
$$2x+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)+y=c,\ x\geq 0 $$ with $c$ be a random parameter. 
$\bullet\ $ Question 1: Can I tell with certainty, that there exist a solution of $(*)$ such that  $y'(x)\leq 0, \ \forall\ x\geq 0$?
$\bullet\ $ Question 2: Can I tell with certainty, that for every solution $y$ of $(*)$ holds $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}y(x)=-\infty$?

About the 1st question, we can see that for every solution $y$ of $(*)$ we can rewrite $(*)$ as $y'=-\dfrac{2x^2+2y^2+x}{x^2+y^2+y},\ x\geq 0$ but i think it's not clearly that $y'(x)\leq 0, \ \forall\ x\geq 0$
About the 2nd question, I tried by contradiction by taking the limit as $x\to+\infty$ to the last equation. However, that didn't end up as I expected.

Any help or suggestion it would be helpful, please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gonçalo , conclusion : I can not tell with certainty that $y'(x)\leq 0, \forall x\geq 0$. Actually,  I write question 1, because I try to use the Monotonicity of solutions with propose to answer negatively about the existence of oscillating solutions (i.e solutions that has infinite countable roots at $[0,+\infty)$). However,  seems that monotonicity doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have every solution of this equation, namely $$
\frac 12\log(y^2+x^2)+y+2x = c,
$$
where $c$ can be calculated after substituting $x=0$ as $c = x_0+\frac 12 \log(x_0^2)$ where $y(0)=x_0$. Note that $c$ can take all real values.

---

> Lemma : Let $y(x),x\geq 0$ be a solution of the differential equation with a value of $c$ which ensures that $y(x) \geq 0$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Then, $y' \leq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.

Observe that if $1\geq x_1>x_0$, then we have $$
\frac{1}{2} \log(y(x_0)^2+x_0^2) + y(x_0)+2x_0 = \frac 12 \log(y(x_1)^2+x_1^2) + y(x_1) + 2x_1 \\ \implies \frac 12 \log\left(\frac{y(x_0)^2+x_0^2}{y(x_1)^2+x_1^2}\right) + (y(x_0)-y(x_1)) = 2x_1-2x_0.
$$

Since both sides are equal to $c$. Suppose that it were true that $y(x_0)<y(x_1)$.Then, the right hand side is positive since $x_1>x_0$. On the other hand, $y(x_0)-y(x_1) \leq 0$ and $y(x_0)^2 + x_0^2 < y(x_1)^2+x_1^2$, since $y(x_0),y(x_1) \geq 0$. This would make the left hand side negative, providing a contradiction.

Therefore, $y$ is monotonically decreasing on $[0,1]$. Since $y$ is differentiable, we obtain using the left derivative that $y' \leq 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

However, if $x \geq 1$, then $x^2+y(x)^2+y \geq 1-\frac 14 \geq \frac 34 > 0$ for all possible values of $y(x)$, and $2x^2+2y(x)^2+x \geq 3 > 0$ for all possible values of $y(x)$. It follows that $y'<0$ for all $x \geq 1$, regardless of the assumption that $y \geq 0$. *The conclusion of this paragraph holds for all solutions*.

proving the proposition. $\blacksquare$

> Lemma : There exists a value of $c$ such that if $y$ is a solution of the differential equation with this value of $c$ then $y(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Proof : We use the intermediate value theorem. Take, say $c=10$. For each $x \in [0,1]$, let $f(y) = \frac 12\log(y^2+x^2) + y+2x - 10$. Observe that $f(0) = \log x + 2x - 10 \leq 2-10 < 0$. On the other hand, $f(50) > \log(50)+50-10 > 0$. Therefore, there is a value $y>0$ such that $f(y) = 0$. In particular, if $x \in [0,1]$ and $\frac 12\log(y(x)^2+x^2)+y(x)+2x = 10$, then $y(x) > 0$. Thus, for $c=10$, we obtain the required result. $\blacksquare$

Combining the lemmas above, we obtain that there exists a solution of the differential equation (namely, that with $c=10$) such that $y' \leq 0$ for all $x\geq 0$.

---

> Lemma : For every value of $c$, the solution satisfies $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x) = -\infty$.

Proof : We already observed that for $x>1$, $y'(x)<0$ regardless of the choice of $c$. Therefore, $y$ is a monotonically decreasing function for $x>1$. We must either have $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x) = L$ for $L < \infty$, or $\lim_{x \to +\infty}y(x) = -\infty$, as a result of this monotonicity.

Suppose that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x) = L$. The function $g(x,y) = \frac 12 \log(y^2+x^2)+y+2x$ is continuous jointly in $y,x$. We have $g(x,y(x)) = c$ for all $x \geq 0$. However, assuming that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}y(x)=L$, there exists $X>0$ large enough such that for $x>X$, $y(x) > L-1$. As a consequence, for all $x>X$, $$
g(x,y(x)) > \frac 12 \log(x^2) + (L-1)+2x > \log(x) + L-1+2x.
$$
However, the left hand side equals $c$ for all $x>X$, while the right hand side converges to $+\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$. This contradicts the inequality and proves that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x) = -\infty$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer was very helpful to me. Moreover, about my 2nd question, If I suppose that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x) = L$ (as you write before), we can also take directly the limit as $x\to +\infty$ on $\frac 12\log(y^2+x^2)+y+2x = c,$ and then we get contradiction because we get $+\infty=c\in\mathbb{R}$